# mail server log - is this possible?

Tags: php, outlook, email

We have a main email account where I work (info@) that at least 4 people receive. Occasionally, someone screws with the outlook settings and makes it start pulling the emails off the server instead of downloading a copy. However, this time, a few emails came through on a couple computers, but didn't come through on one. Then I checked the online web mail, and email no longer existed.

So here is my question. I basically want to setup a proxy email server that logs information. That way when critical emails are deleted, I can find out when and why.

Any ideas how to implement this? is there already something out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your email server probably supports distribution lists. Have the info account be a list, and not a mailbox.

If the server doesn't have that facility built in, I would probably install a copy of [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) and use that to achieve the same effect (with the option of archiving built in).

Comment: +1 this is probably the way to go. Adding a 'proxy email server' just introduces complexity and risk.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite following. What would a distribution list do for me? Would that just send emails to everyone, instead of them having to download direct from the mail server?

Comment: It will, effectively, forward the email to multiple other email addresses. They then get handled normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a service that listens on port 110 for POP3 and 143 for IMAP, logs all traffic and forwards it to your mail server, and then turns around and forwards the response back to the client (after logging of course).